# Error When we read from excel using python

Tags: python, excel

_locate_stream
    raise CompDocError("%s corruption: seen[%d] == %d" % (qname, s, self.seen[s]))
xlrd.compdoc.CompDocError: Workbook corruption: seen[2] == 4

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What did you try, what do you want to ask? Do you have some minimal, complete anf verifiable example?

Comment: Hi, When I download an Excel file and opened to read that file, the following error appears.   
    xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('BBB2018.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 441, in open_workbook
    raise CompDocError("%s corruption: seen[%d] == %d" % (qname, s, self.seen[s]))
xlrd.compdoc.CompDocError: Workbook corruption: seen[2] == 4

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: In short: I guess the excel file is corrupt...

Answer (score -1):

In my case, simply opening the file on LibreOffice or Excel and saving a copy of it solved the issue. I was able to open the copy with pandas.

I learned this on [an issue](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/149) on xlrd repository.